# Strange graph plotted using k means clustering

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, k-means

I have a dataframe which consists details of hundreds of films. I used details of a film such as rental rate and length to do a k-means clustering. When I plot the k-means clustering graph, the graph is just three vertical bars. Is it because there is correlation between the attributes? Can someone explain in more details? Thanks!!

```
le= LabelEncoder()


#factors such as release_year, rental rate etc
#Do k_means clustering based on the factors.
factors_attributes=homework_film[['rental_rate','length','language_id']]

# Label encoding: transform string into numbers
#factors_attributes['rating'] =le.fit_transform(factors_attributes['rating'])


#The code below finds the optimal K for clustering
#The graph shows that the optimal K is 3 for this model
Sum_of_squared_distances=[]
Sum=[]
K=range(1,15)
for k in K:
    clustering=KMeans(n_clusters=k)
    clustering=clustering.fit(factors_attributes)
    Sum_of_squared_distances.append(clustering.inertia_)

plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(K,Sum_of_squared_distances, 'bx-')
plt.xlabel('k')
plt.ylabel('Sum_of_squared_distances')
plt.title('Elbow Method for Optimal K')
plt.show()

# The code below finds the best iteration for clustering
# The graph shows that iteration is about 9

I=range(1,50)
for i in I:
    clustering=KMeans(n_clusters=3, max_iter=i)
    clustering=clustering.fit(factors_attributes)
    Sum.append(clustering.inertia_)

plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.plot(I,Sum, 'bx-')
plt.xlabel('I')
plt.ylabel('Sum_of_squared_distances')
plt.title('Elbow Method for optimal I')
plt.subplot
plt.show()



colorMap=np.array(['red','lime','black'])


plt.subplot(2,2,2)
finalC=KMeans(n_clusters=3, max_iter=9)
finalC=finalC.fit(factors_attributes)
plt.scatter(x=factors_attributes.length,y=factors_attributes.rental_rate,c=colorMap[finalC.labels_],s=50)

(factors_attributes.rental_rate,y=factors_attributes.length,c=colorMap[predicts.labels_],s=50)

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: Head of dataset]
[image: result graph]

Comment: A code sample and look at a small piece of data would help a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your plot the film `rental_rate` is the y-axis. inside your data-sample I can see only two different values (`0.99` and `4.99`) these are two of the horizontal bars (top and bottom). Probably there are also `rental_rates` with a value of `2.99` --> middle horizontal bar. So there are only three distinct values of a `rental_rate`.

Your x-axis is the film `length`, that seems to be a continuous variable within a range of ~45 and 200. Combined with the `language_id` and the `rental_rate` you use these tree features inside k-means and force the model to have `n_clusters=3` clusters. Now k-means tries to break the data into three clusters (red, black, green) but it seems to be that the `length` variable has the most influence, because the clusters are only separated by this one. `rental_rate` has no (significant) effect and also probably `language_id` seems not to contribute to the model.

I think you expected, that the films are clusters by the `rental_rate` or at least not by `length` alone. With your data it is not the case, because k-means uses a distance metric (euclidean distance by default) as an optimization objective, and so the "absolute values" of the features matters a lot. So, because the range of the feature `length` is much wider in absolute values `~[45,200]` in comparison to the other features (`[1,5]` and `[1,X]`), it has the most effect on the clustering, when the euclidean distance between two samples is calculated.

One possible solution would be to normalize your data/features.